# python-eve array field contains query

Tags: python, eve

I understand eve is by default using mongodb as backend, and mongodb actually support indexing/query on array field ([doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)) e.g.

```
db.inventory.find( { tags: { $in: [ /^be/, /^st/ ] } } )
```

do we support the same in eve? if not, how far are we (want to estimate whether I need to make some change in the schema - not ideal though)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supported:

```
/?where={"tags": {"$in": ["programming"]}}
```

Regex are not allowed in there thought.